# Can't exit Salesforce Development Mode

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

When I have the Development mode enabled for my profile, and I open a custom VisualForce page, the code-editing window/frame appears on the bottom of the screen.

Problem: for 7-8 months now, this window does not disappear when I am done with the custom VF page and go on to strandard pages.  It's just sitting there, and displays the code for the original VF page.  In addition to that, it's keeping the custom VF's URL up in the address bar of the browser, which interferes with other VF pages which take a use of the URL data.

I have submitted this as an issue to SF Support, who had pounded on it for months, and did not resolve.

Have you experienced this problem before, or know how to fix?

Comment: What internet browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before and found the Development Mode toolbar at the bottom of pages particularly annoying. It doesn't work with some of the Firefox plugins that I use. So, I turned it off.

To edit a page without Development Mode turned on, go to Setup > Develop > Pages (or Apex Classes for controllers).

If you'd rather keep Development Mode on you may want to try updating your browser, or try using a different browser ([Internet Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie), [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/), [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)).

Comment: I am having this issue in various browsers intermittently.  Can't pinpoint the exact conditions to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the url parameter

`core.apexpages.devmode.url=1`

in the address of any VF page to temporarily disable the development Mode toolbar.